# How to do a rolling/running subtraction while simultaneously updating the principal amount?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Supposing a `data frame` like the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(product = paste0("product", 1:4)) %>% 
  mutate(moneyAvailable = 20,
         productPrice = rnorm(n = nrow(.), mean = 7, sd = 1))
df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   product  moneyAvailable productPrice
#>   <chr>             <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 product1             20         6.53
#> 2 product2             20         8.67
#> 3 product3             20         6.15
#> 4 product4             20         6.60
```

I would like to calculate a running total that, for the 1st row, subtracts `productPrice` from `moneyAvailable`, but use the resulting value to subtract from the `productPrice` in 2nd row, and so on...

The final result will be like the following (which I am hard-coding).
My own attempt was to try to use a combination of `lag` from `dplyr` and `cumsum` but they were not relevant here.

```r
df1$moneyRemaining = c(14.77, 6.95, 0.86, -7.05)
df1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   product  moneyAvailable productPrice moneyRemaining
#>   <chr>             <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 product1             20         6.53          14.8 
#> 2 product2             20         8.67           6.95
#> 3 product3             20         6.15           0.86
#> 4 product4             20         6.60          -7.05
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: IIUC, `moneyAvailable - cumsum(productPrice)`? But, I am wondering about your expected result. In the first row I would expect `moneyRemaining` = 20 - 6.53 = 13.47

Comment: @Uwe thank you so much, this was right under the nose while I looked for functions from dplyr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve it. We use `row_number` to figure out the transaction order. If it's the first transaction, we do `money - price`, otherwise we just subtract the price, using `cumsum`.

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
    mutate(moneyRemaining = cumsum(ifelse(rownum == 1, 
                                          moneyAvailable - productPrice, 
                                          -productPrice)))

#   product  moneyAvailable productPrice rownum moneyRemaining
#   <chr>             <dbl>        <dbl>  <int>          <dbl>
# 1 product1             20         6.87      1         13.1  
# 2 product2             20         5.90      2          7.23 
# 3 product3             20         6.58      3          0.649
# 4 product4             20         6.11      4         -5.46
```

On a larger data set (maybe having multiple customers), you'd want to make sure your data is sorted correctly (`arrange`), and then you could use `group_by`.